# Identify this educational Japanese cartoon show

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

This show was a big hit in the 80s when it aired in the Middle East (dubbed into Arabic).

The show is about a school boy and his sister who encounter various topics each episode and are assisted by a little humanoid creature (a female character that has two long hair braids on each of her sides. These braids act as her hands, since she has no hands).

The character is very smart and acts as an encyclopedia to the children. She takes them back in time to reveal the back story behind inventions, discoveries, etc.
Sometimes she takes them to the future to predict what technology would be capable of.

I remember one episode, where this character predicted Caller ID and FaceTime!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, a fellow fan of "اسألوا لبيبة" :)

The Japanese name is ["Miimu Iro Iro Yume no Tabi"](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1778) (Mimu, the Traveller of Many Dreams)

[image: Meemu]

As an aside, the site www.animenewsnetwork.com is an excellent resource for these sorts of question since they have the names of many anime in multiple languages (including Arabic).

Comment: When my vote count resets, +1 just for whatever is written in the first line :) This looks like a great find.

Comment: @AndrewMartin - LOL that's the Arabic name of that particular series. It's a childhood favorite of mine :)